# rosrun can't able to find executable of rviz

Tags: rviz, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I removed rviz from ros-groovy

```
$ sudo apt-get remove ros-groovy-rviz
```

After that from backup i coppied rviz folder into /opt/ros/groovy/share then

```
$ rosdep install rviz

$ rosmake rviz
```

rosdep and rosmake doesn't give any error. After that when i tried

```
rosrun rviz rviz
```

It is giving following error:

```
pr2admin@basestation:~$ rosrun rviz rviz

[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named rviz below /opt/ros/groovy/share/rviz

[rosrun] Found the following, but they're either not files,

[rosrun] or not executable:

[rosrun]   /opt/ros/groovy/share/rviz
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226796/rosrun-can%27t-able-to-find-executable-of-rviz/) by [mathpati.nikhil](https://answers.ros.org/users/25204/mathpati.nikhil/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The executable is actually in `/opt/ros/groovy/lib/rviz/`, not in `share`.
You didn't copy this. This is why it is not working at all.

Also you  shouldn't just copy all this stuff over from a backup, because then you cannot install or update rviz. Why don't you just install it again via `apt-get`?

That there are no errors when you do a `rosmake` is just becaus there are no makefiles in the `rviz` package. This is compeltely unnecessary here.

If you want to use a specific version of `rviz`, better build this specific version from source and have it in your workspace...

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1